# Activating environment in virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, opencv, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

i installed `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` and with this command i created an environment:

```
mkvirtualenv cv
```

it works and after creating i was in the new environment. right now i restarted my computer and i want to `activate` that environment again, but how?

i use this tutorial to install Opencv on my Mac and one of steps is creating new environment. im confused right now:

```
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/
```

i uses `virtualenv` already but im new to `virtualenvwrapper` and i dont know what i have to do now

Answer (score 12):

To activate an environment, we use `workon` command.

```
workon cv
```

If you forget the virtualenv name, you can just type:

```
workon
```

And you will see a list of available environments.

Comment: when i do this, i get this error: ERROR: Environment '/Users/myname/.virtualenvs/cv' does not contain an activate script

Comment: Manually navigate to that directory and see if the activate script exists. If not, remove the environment using `rmvirtualenv` and recreate it.

Comment: I am having the same issue. And the activation script is there.

Answer (score 2):

virtualenvwrapper works best if you use `mkproject` instead of `mkvirtualenv`. This makes a virtualenv *and* a project directory to put your files that use the virtualenv. After that you can use `workon` to switch back to your virtualenv and project.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem because I misread the docs and accidentally specified the directory where I put my repos as my `$WORKON_HOME`, so virtualenvwrapper couldn't find my virtualenvs.

`$WORKON_HOME` should actually be where your virtualenvs live (I like to make mine at `~/.virtualenvs`). This is where the command `mkvirtualenv` creates the virtualenv for your project. Set this environment variables in your `.bashrc` (or equivalent), make sure your new `$WORKON_HOME` directory exists, and then make a new virtualenv. That should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Read the Docs](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html#workon)

> ## workon
>
> List or change working virtual environments

```
$ workon cv
```

Comment: when i do this, i get this error: ERROR: Environment '/Users/myname/.virtualenvs/cv' does not contain an activate script.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same problem.
So first I uninstalled virtualenvwrapper using,

```
$ sudo pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper
```

Then I performed the documentation steps again with some changes this time. You can also do the same, it will work.

**Install Steps**

1. `$ sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper`
2. Now create a directory to store your virtual environment

   `$ mkdir ~/.virtualenvs`
3. Now,

   `$ export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs`
4. Now you have to open .bashrc file and add one line to it.

   So, to do this first copy the line written below and then run,
   `$ nano .bashrc`
   And now paste it at the end of the script

   . /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

   This will add virtualenvwrapper.sh to .bashrc
5. Now run ,

   `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`
6. Finally run to reload .bashrc,

   `source ~/.bashrc`
7. **Finally** you can use 
   `mkvirtualenv` and `workon` commands without any problem.

Hope it helps.