# Installation fails Virtualenvwrapper and Virtualenvs does not contains an activate script

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, virtualenv, raspberry-pi3, virtualenvwrapper

I use a RPI3B and try to install Virtualenvwrapper and Virtualenvs. After i add the

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

in the ~/.profile. Then `source ~ ~/.profile`
I use `mkvirtualenv cv -p python2`. After that i get these message :

```
created virtual environment CPython2.7.16.final.0-32 in 672ms
creator CPython2Posix(dest=/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv, clear=False, global=False)
seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=latest, setuptools=latest, wheel=latest, via=copy, 
app_data_dir=/home/pi/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-v1)
activators PythonActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,BashActivator
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/usr/local/bin/predeactivate
ERROR: Environment '/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv' does not contain an activate script.
```

But i cant use workon cv. The last Message come again and again. How can i fix it? 
I also try it to reinstall but it doesnt help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Activating environment in virtualenvwrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34239037/activating-environment-in-virtualenvwrapper)

Comment: Something here helps? https://stackoverflow.com/q/60252119/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenvwrapper%5D+Environment+does+not+contain+an+activate+script

Comment: thanks. To Fix it the you need to install virtualwrapper version 4.8.4 than it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same error message when I used `mkvirtualenv` on a new RPI4. I added these lines to my `.bashrc` and it fixed the problem for me:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_ENV_BIN_DIR=bin  # <== This line fixed it for me
```

Comment: This was the exact error I had at the exact same step.  The answer by Jeff Bass indeed solved my problem too.