# virtualenvwrapper does not create an activate script

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv

I've been using virtualenvwrapper for years, not sure what has changed.

```
$ mkvirtualenv foobar
created virtual environment CPython3.10.4.final.0-64 in 110ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/chris/.virtualenvs/foobar, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/chris/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==22.1.2, setuptools==62.6.0, wheel==0.37.1
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/chris/.virtualenvs/foobar/bin/predeactivate
ERROR: Environment '/home/chris/.virtualenvs/foobar' does not contain an activate script.
```

And that is true -- the newly created /home/chris/.virtualenvs/foobar directory doesn't even have a "bin" directory.

I've seen this post, but the fixes there don't change anything:

[Installation fails Virtualenvwrapper and Virtualenvs does not contains an activate script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60386143/installation-fails-virtualenvwrapper-and-virtualenvs-does-not-contains-an-activa)

I'm running Ubuntu 2022.04, fully patched.

**UPDATE**

I suspect that the issue was caused by conflicts between packages installed via `apt get`, `sudo pip3 install`, etc.  Things are probably not helped by the new pattern of installing packages in `.local`.  (My system is pretty old and has gone through a lot of OS and Python upgrades.)

In any case, I was able to get this working by:

1. Installing pyenv
2. Within pyenv, installing python 3.9
3. Setting 3.9 as the default python in pyenv
4. initializing my pipenv with `pipenv shell 'pyenv which python'` (those should be backticks)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, it creates it in local/bin directory. Move bin up one level and run mkvirtualenv script again. Also you need to change path in 'pip' and 'wheel' files inside bin.
To pip developers: please don't touch what's working!

Comment: Indeed, in my case a "broken" installation of python site packages had slipped into `~/.local`, in particular yet another `pip` version. Removing `~/.local/bin` and `~/.local/lib` (after verifying it contained only undesired Python stuff) solved the issue for me.

Comment: This solved my issue, but when I'm inside the virtualenv cmd cannot find pip. What do you mean by change path in 'pip' and 'wheel' files inside bin? What do I have to do exactly?

Comment: @FerranCapalleraGuirado open those two files with text editor and change first line to the actual path.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue has occurred to me , I have made a few of command lines on terminal of linux in the following:

1. pip install --upgrade pip (my pip shown that it was not updated)
2. pip install --upgrade virtualenv
3. pip install --upgrade virtualenvwrapper

After the above command lines, and then I tried command "mkvirtualenv" for making new virtualenv and it was successful.